# How do I make Ruby YAML.load parse times the way I want them?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have YAML file, with a Date in it. I want to direct how `YAML.load(file)` parses it.

```
---
to_date: 2021-02-15T06:00:00
```

I want to parse this in Ruby, using `yaml = YAML.load(file)` The problem is that the date gets parsed automatically as a `DateTime` object. That is:

```
> yaml["to_date"]
=> #<DateTime: 2021-02-15T06:00:00+00:00 ((2459261j,21600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I would like `YAML.load(file)` to do one of two things:

- Leave it as a string, so I can convert it, or
- Use Time.parse instead of DateTime.parse.

The reason is that since my local is EST (-05:00) `Time.parse` takes the local timezone into account, whereas DateTime.parse does not, defaulting to UTC.

```
> Time.parse("2021-02-15T06:00:00")
=> 2021-02-15 06:00:00 -0500

> DateTime.parse("2021-02-15T06:00:00")
=> #<DateTime: 2021-02-15T06:00:00+00:00 ((2459261j,21600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

What are some options to give to `YAML` or `YAML.load` that I may use to direct how this date gets parsed?

Modifying the input to include the timezone or using !str or putting the dates in quotes is NOT an option. So, please do not suggest that.

Comment: Given that's a [YAML timestamp](https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html), you're basically asking how to make `YAML.load` non-compliant with the YAML specification ;) **"If the time zone is omitted, the timestamp is assumed to be specified in UTC"**

Comment: Why is fixing the incorrect input not an option? It would make more sense to fix this error upstream rather than hack a fix in later. Like, for example, you could traverse the parsed YAML to check for any `DateTime` values and change the timezone, but that's a really awkward workaround.

Comment: There's a third option, convert the DateTimes.

Comment: The problem is that the yaml file is generated by some other software/person not under my control, and it needs to be time zone agnostic. For example, person A says you must do something at Date X at 9am and that is going to be regardless of what timezone you are in and if it is daylight savings or not. Note, the Date would be optional as well.  Person A may be in a different timezone than the system reading the YAML file. It is like some Pilates instructor in Hungary saying do a certain exercise at 9:00 to everybody around the world.